# How to connect Windows login name with database UserID

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I've created users in my database and granted permissions, but how do I connect the username with userID column which i have in my database.For an example,  the username (windows) is John and he has permissions in database that he can insert data into tables.There is a Usertable in my database and John´s ID is 25459 which is the primary key. I need somehow to connect the ID and Windows Login, so that the program i write in c# "knows" that if im logged in as John, i have ID 25459.

Answer (score 0):

Direct Answer:
The "Windows Login" is the UserPrincipal.UserName.

Suggestion:
If you have control of the SQL Server (not DBA), set up your permission there instead of rolling your own.

Comment: i have control of the server and i did that but i need to connect a windows/sql username (which is already set with permissions on the server) with the userID in the table. For an example i have a program to issue a bill for the purchase and it´s connected to the database. when i press "print the bill" button it should print out the bill with the userID number on it, which i should get from the server. So if the John is logged on to windows his userID should be 14546, for Jack is 345565, for an example. So i should connect the users with their UserIDs in the database

Comment: Since you want to maintain that table, you might be confusing the DisplayName from the UserName (aka SAMAccountName). Use the SAMAccountName that you get from C#, which is the Pricipal.UserName.

Comment: well there is no use for me with the samaccountname. i have a user called PC1\JACK in my login folder in sql server (which is connected with my windows account). i have to somehow map it to the UserID in my SalesStaff table and to be able to pull out his ID from my c# program.My UserID for Staff is the social security number, so it can´t be samaccount.

Comment: The UserID is a generated number, no one knows that number except for the application. Therefore, your user table should contain a field that has PC1\JACK. Consider the login folder independent from your user table. Use C# to lookup PC1\JACK (UserName) against your user table to return 14546.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i can´t do that, my assignment is to have a social security number as UserID (primary key) and to have full name of the user in the table. And i shouldn´t look up the user from c# program, it should be automatically. if im logged in windows as Jack, program should already know that(because it runs under windows) and therefore when i access the database it´s already "known" what restrictions i have. I should find a way to connect a table field-UserID with windows login